# How to renew MWS merchant API Key

Tags: amazon-mws

I wonder how we can renew the Amazon merchant API key.

Is there an API call for this, or what is the procedure?

I googled a great amount but only find the procedure to request the first key, which does not work anymore if you are already using the API

We have the old data and are using them but it was compromised, so we need at least a new secret key.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a forum message which seems to answer it https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3015879

"Yes, you can change your MWS secret key. Whenever you want to do that we will delete your MWS secret key from our end, and then you can sign up for MWS again to get new secret key through this link

https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html/182-5557423-3858158 "

Answer (score 2):

There is now no way to reset your own keys (that I can see). Instead you need to contact MWS support and ask them to do it for you.

This can be done via:
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html
https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html

If you put something like "URGENT - MWS Keys Compromised" in the subject line then they should respond quickly!